# What are the conditions, for $n$ matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ ... $A_n$ etc, such that their Hadamard product and Matrix products are identical?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the possible family of matrices $A_1$, ... , $A_n$ such that their Hadamard (elementwise) products and matrix products are equivalent, and is it valid as $n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$?

I.e.:

$A_1\odot A_2\cdots\odot A_{n-1}\odot A_n = A_1A_2\cdots A_{n-1}A_n$

I realise this is true for diagonal matrices, but was wondering what is the set of matrices that this holds true.
Thanks

Comment: Something to try: Take n = 2 and work with mxm matrices, for small m. You can write down the conditions for equality as a bunch of polynomial equations on the entries.  Plug into Macaulay2 and see if it tells you anything interesting about the ideal : https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/TryItOut/ You can produce the equations with a small program - I definitely wouldn't want to type them all up by hand beyond the m = 2 or 3 case.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for $2\times 2$ matrices, there are already many possibilities.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad$ trivial case $B=0$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&d\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&v\end{pmatrix}\quad$ triangular case

$A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac cu(u-v)&c\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}s&u\\0&v\end{pmatrix}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}s&0\\0&v\end{pmatrix}\quad$ diagonal case

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}s&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad$ triangular case

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&\frac bt(t-s)\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}s&0\\t&v\end{pmatrix}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}s&u\\t&v\end{pmatrix}\quad$ trivial case $A=0$

There are $2$ cases I did not annotate since I think this won't probably extend to higher dimensions nor multiple matrices, but you may want to have look at the triangular case for higher dimensions.

---

Edit:

Here is for $3\times 3$ matrices (given the size, I'm forced to make it a link so it will disappear after some time sorry...).

It looks like this is not extending well to bigger dimension, basically only $1$ row or $1$ column matrices and zero elsewhere seems to behave correctly.

https://www.docdroid.net/bQn19yo/toto-pdf

Thus I suspect that for multiple matrices, you will end up with all non-diagonal elements of the product forced to be zeroes, and that the diagonal case will be the only one relevant.